# What to do when a roll resolves as nothing?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

I ran the Age of Rebellion Starter Game for a bunch of my friends, and numerous times during combat, they rolled and got a blank end result - no Successes, no Failures, and no Advantages or Disadvantages.

How am I supposed to treat that as the GM? I wasn't really able to react to that well, and it really turned us off of the system. Is there a rule I'm missing on how to resolve this kind of result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be clear, per rules no success = failure. When all success symbols are canceled, you don't need additional failure symbols to consider it a fail check. The blank result in your example is by default a failure.

I don't have the Age of Rebellion Starter Game, but it's stated on the core rules page 30.

Answer (score 8):

If this is a combat roll then at least one success is required to have any effect - in the case where everything cancelled you just miss, in a boring and not very cinematic way.

If it is a non-combat roll you just fail to make any progress but there are no other consequences.